# Detect is element is visible (Not blocked by native PDF viewer)

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I am using the browser native PDF viewer. To implement a loading spinner I positioned the PDF viewer above a loading spinner. Was wondering if theres a way to detect if the loading indicator is still visible after sometime?

Comment: what is the PDF viewer? an iframe? a popup window?

Comment: Its an object tag `<object type="application/pdf" data="URL` @JaromandaX

Comment: have you tried using the object load event to detect when it's loaded?